# jQuery: how to check if child is first and also last

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am trying to set a custom style for elements that are

- ul - the first in many children (ul.first)
- last in many children (ul.last)
- the only child (ul.first.last or ul.only)

HTML:

```
<ul class="selector">
    <li class="selector">some li
       <ul class="">
          <li>some fancy li - the ul parent should have first class</li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="">
          <li>some more li - the ul parent should have last class</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="selector">some second li
        <ul class="">
          <li>some lonely li - the ul parent should have first and last classes</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

so I came up with a piece of jQuery hoping to do the trick

```
$('ul.selector li.selector > ul').each(function () {
  if ($(this).is(':first') && $(this).is(':last')) {
    $(this).addClass('first last');
  } else if ($(this).is(':first')) {
    $(this).addClass('first');
  } else if ($(this).is(':last')) {
    $(this).addClass('last');
  }
});
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

UPDATE - here is a fiddle you can play with, based on one of the answers: http://jsfiddle.net/qAtpe/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just this :

```
$('ul.selector li.selector > ul').each(function() {
    $this = $(this); // cache $(this)
    if ($this.is(':first')) {
        $this.addClass('first'); 
    } 
    if ($this.is(':last')) {
        $this.addClass('last'); 
    }
});
```

Then use the following CSS

```
.first {
    //this is first
}
.last { 
    // this is last
}
.first.last {
    // this is first and last - ie the only child
}
```

### Update

```
$('ul.selector li.selector > ul').each(function() {
    $this = $(this); // cache $(this)
    if ($this.is(':first-child')) {
        $this.addClass('first'); 
    } 
    if ($this.is(':last-child')) {
        $this.addClass('last'); 
    }
});
​
```

Looking at your example jsfiddle - you needed the selector `:first-child` rather and `:first` ..

> The :first pseudo-class is equivalent to :eq(0). It could also be written as :lt(1). While this matches only a single element, :first-child can match more than one: One for each parent.

This now works :

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qAtpe/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the element has any siblings, otherwise it's an only child :

```
$('ul.selector li.selector > ul').each(function() {
    if ($(this).siblings().length===0)) {
        $(this).addClass('only'); 
    } else if ($(this).is(':first') ) {
        $(this).addClass('first'); 
    } else if ($(this).is(':last') ) {
        $(this).addClass('last'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is interesting. I am better learning what siblings do. It does not work. Thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but you can use the selector below to select LI elements that are alone, not comes before/after another LI :

```
$('ul:first-child:last-child')
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one case for that

If child is first and last it will be one in mumber, so use

```
$('ul.selector li.selector > ul').children().length ==1
```

it number of child is 1.

and don't use :first it will not work in IE

Comment: Indent by 4 spaces for code not `>` and `:first` will work with IE (all versions) in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
$('ul.selector li.selector > ul').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);

    if  ( $this.is(':first') && $this.is(':last') ) {
        $this.addClass('first last'); 
    } else {

        if ($this.is(':first')) {
           $this.addClass('first'); 
        } 

        if ($this.is(':last')) {
            $this.addClass('last'); 
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: what are you doing different than in the question ? (other than caching ?)

Comment: I presumed his jQuery was wrong as he had asked the question. Also i removed his multiple if statements

Comment: I can accept yours if you can make it work. Check my question updates for a fiddle. None of the answers help me so far :|

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/KCAZQ/.  If there's only one element I'm assuming these will cover it as well.

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>thrid</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
</ul>

$('ul').find('li').first().css('color','green');
$('ul').find('li').last().css('color','green');
```

Comment: I didn't directly answer your question, but this gets you on the right track and hopefully helps you in your understanding of jQuery.

Comment: Your code is adding some class, I checked here
http://jsfiddle.net/KCAZQ/4/

But it's not working on all, but only the first encountered.

Comment: /\ Maybe I should use each()   :)

Comment: Doing `.first().last()` isn't going to work the way you want. If the `.each()` examples are working then use them. I just wanted to show you a different approach.

Comment: I love different approaches. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while looking for the same issue trying to get the last `li > a` in my breadcrumbs that was not the first `li`.  Here's how I solved it:

```
$(".breadcrumb > li:gt(0):last > a")
```